# How to retrieve specific value from list of Json Object in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, foreach

I'm trying the below code to retrieve the **executionArn** but I'm getting this error

```
Error [SyntaxError]: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

How to get **executionArn** or **stateMachineArn** from each record? Any help would be much appreciated.

**console.log(data) - Output**

```
{
  executions: [
    {
      executionArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-2:12222:execution:test:dcb689bc',
      stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-2:12222:stateMachine:test-sm',
      name: 'test-name',
      status: 'SUCCEEDED',
      startDate: 2021-06-17T13:43:39.817Z,
      stopDate: 2021-06-17T13:43:53.667Z
    },
    {
      executionArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-2:12222:execution:test:sd32dsdf',
      stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-2:12222:stateMachine:test-sm',
      name: 'test-name1',
      status: 'SUCCEEDED',
      startDate: 2021-06-17T13:43:39.817Z,
      stopDate: 2021-06-17T13:43:53.667Z
    }
  ],
  nextToken: 'aadfdfdf'
}
```

**Code:**

```
  stepfunctions.listExecutions(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
    else     
    console.log(data)
    //console.log(data.executions[0].executionArn)
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    data.forEach(function(result) {
        var arnValue = result.executions.executionArn;
        console.log(arnValue);
    });

  });
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data)`? Please be aware that the input is not valid JSON.

Comment: Updated my post - pls check this console.log(data) - Output

Comment: `data` looks like it's a JavaScript object, not JSON. There should be no need to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: If I don't use JSON.parse then its giving me a data.forEach is not a function :(

Comment: Probably because `data` is an object which doesn't have that function. Try using `data.executions.forEach` instead?

Answer (score 1):

data is an object and executions inside it is an array, so try this

```
data.executions.foreach(function (execution) {
  console.log('executionArn', execution.executionArn)
  console.log('stateMachineArn', execution.stateMachineArn)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
executions.map(e=>{
   // access it here
   let a =  e.executionArn;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided output (data) is not a valid JSON object,

```
{...
  startDate: 2021-06-17T13:43:39.817Z,
  stopDate: 2021-06-17T13:43:53.667Z
}
```

For valid JSON, it should look like

```
{...
  "startDate": "2021-06-17T13:43:39.817Z",
  "stopDate": "2021-06-17T13:43:53.667Z"
}
```

for it to be iterated correctly.

If the data is from the server (API), stringify the dates before returning them, and the values could be found by

```js
  data.executions.map(execution=>{
      let arnValue = execution.executionArn;
      console.log(arnValue);
  })
```

Comment: The JSON example is not valid JSON. Also [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: thanks @evolutionxbx. Its a common mistake we make as developers.